# Is it possible to write xml into json object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, json

I'm having issues in javascript with putting a var that contains xml string into a object and then send it via ajax with jQuery.

The question would be: is it possible to have a xml string into a json object ?

```
{"a":"a","b":"b", "xml":"<test r='r'></test>"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the use case? It's like asking about creating Frankenstein's monster...

Comment: Yes. What's the problem?

Comment: THe problem is that the web service isn't receiving the get request when sending a object like this, so I think it's a parse error

Comment: You need to HTML-encode strings, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding

Comment: It's possible, in jQuery you can use $(data.xml) to create a Dom object and parse it. But are you really sure that you need it in that way?

Comment: Thanks to jhon pick for the correct answer.

Comment: for documentation purposes, could you please transform your comment into an answer @John_Pick sothat Eric can pick it as correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Your XML will be like this:

```
&lt; test r=&quot;r&quot;&gt; &lt;&#x2F;test&gt;
```

Replace as follows:

```
& = &amp;

" = &quot;

' = &#39;

< = &lt;

> = &gt;

/ = &#x2F;
```

Comment: In general for all XMLs, are there any other characters that need to be replaced?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, of course. Your code is working well:

```
var obj = {"a":"a","b":"b", "xml":"<test r='r'></test>"}
alert(obj.xml)
```

Comment: actually no, I was needing to html encode it, just as John Pick answered