# storing xml inside json object

Tags: xml, json, storing-information

I need to store complete XML document as part of JSON object.
when i receive the request and try to create JSON object from JSON string like below:

```
{"content":{
"name" : "xyz",
"details":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
 <ns0:Report xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.khisko.com/triTypes\">
  <StackTrace>Job-8004 Error in [xxxxxxxxxx]
      Output data invalid&#xD;
  at com.xyz.tst.a(Unknown Source)&#xD;
      caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException&#xD;
   </StackTrace>
   <Msg>Output data invalid</Msg>
  </ns0:Report>"
 }}
```

I am getting Unterminated string error at first char of details.
How can I handle it?

I am using `org.json.JSONObject` constructor which takes java string as parameter and passing above JSON as java string.

Comment: Remove the line breaks from the xml

Comment: and why in gods name do you want to put xml inside json ?

Comment: xml is request received from client which i need to preserve.

Comment: @varun - because you need to support a new feature in an existing code base without disrupting other existing functionality :( ;)

Answer (score 29):

You can encode and decode xml string like

```
{
  "content": {
    "name": "xyz",
    "details": "PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj1cIjEuMFwiIGVuY29kaW5nPVwiVVRGLThcIj8+CiA8bnMwOlJlcG9ydCB4bWxuczpuczA9XCJodHRwOi8vd3d3LmtoaXNrby5jb20vdHJpVHlwZXNcIj4KICA8U3RhY2tUcmFjZT5Kb2ItODAwNCBFcnJvciBpbiBbeHh4eHh4eHh4eF0KICAgICAgT3V0cHV0IGRhdGEgaW52YWxpZCYjeEQ7CiAgYXQgY29tLnh5ei50c3QuYShVbmtub3duIFNvdXJjZSkmI3hEOwogICAgICBjYXVzZWQgYnk6IGphdmEubGFuZy5OdWxsUG9pbnRlckV4Y2VwdGlvbiYjeEQ7CiAgIDwvU3RhY2tUcmFjZT4KICAgPE1zZz5PdXRwdXQgZGF0YSBpbnZhbGlkPC9Nc2c+CiAgPC9uczA6UmVwb3J0Pg==",
    "encoding": "base64"
  }
}
```

Comment: To do encoding and decoding in client JavaScript use atob() and btoa(). Here is MDN doc link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding

Comment: I was wondering why this answer was not marked as the right answer until I saw it is posted 6 years after the question :)

Comment: I don't find this answer clear tbh. You have hashed the XML? What if you get that xml from a db and you have to store it as it is in the json file?

Comment: @Zizzipupp looks like base64 encoding to me.  Just google base64 to find the appropriate .Net call. e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-5.0 e.g. code: public static String ToBase64String(this String source) {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(source));
    }

Answer (score 14):

Just I've changed `\"` to `'` and `remove line breaks` like @Explosion Pills says

```
{"content":{
    "name" : "xyz",
    "details":"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <ns0:Report xmlns:ns0='http://www.khisko.com/triTypes'>
      <StackTrace>Job-8004 Error in [xxxxxxxxxx]
          Output data invalid&#xD;
      at com.xyz.tst.a(Unknown Source)&#xD;
          caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException&#xD;
       </StackTrace>
       <Msg>Output data invalid</Msg>
      </ns0:Report>"
     }}
```

Comment: actually the original question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264470/is-it-possible-to-write-xml-into-json-object but that Thread has the answer hidden in a comment.
I have a similar need and will try this approach, I guess this comes closest to XML's CDATA element.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't want to remove the line breaks from the XML so I've changed the Java class that handles the JSON to not throw unterminated string exceptions for newlines or carriage returns.