# Putting xml as a value of a json object in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl

i am try to get the json output below so that i send it to an API

```
 { "payload": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n<ns0:BulkMessage xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"\r\nxmlns:ns0=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema\"\r\nxsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema BulkMessageSchema.xsd\">\r\n<ns0:bulkType>SINGLE</ns0:bulkType>\r\n<ns0:singleMessage>\r\n<ns0:message>Sample single bulk message</ns0:message>\r\n<ns0:reference>hfhdjfdkljfjdlkfjkd</ns0:reference>\r\n<ns0:mobileNumbers>0773562319</ns0:mobileNumbers>\r\n<ns0:mobileNumbers>0774705932</ns0:mobileNumbers>\r\n<ns0:category>PROMOTIONAL</ns0:category>\r\n</ns0:singleMessage>\r\n</ns0:BulkMessage>", }
```

But somehow when the xml is inserted into the Json it ignores certain characters and i end up having the output below:

```
{   "payload": "SINGLE<\/ns0:bulkType>Sample single bulk message<\/ns0:message>hfhdjfdkljfjdlkfjkd<\/ns0:reference>0773562319<\/ns0:mobileNumbers>0774705932<\/ns0:mobileNumbers>PROMOTIONAL<\/ns0:category><\/ns0:singleMessage><\/ns0:BulkMessage>",}
```

Below is the php code that encoding the JSON

```
  $payload = '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'.
'<ns0:BulkMessage xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema BulkMessageSchema.xsd\">'.
'<ns0:bulkType>SINGLE</ns0:bulkType>'.
'<ns0:singleMessage>'.
'<ns0:message>Sample single bulk message</ns0:message>'.
'<ns0:reference>'.$uid.'</ns0:reference>'.
'<ns0:mobileNumbers>0773562319</ns0:mobileNumbers>'.
'<ns0:mobileNumbers>0774705932</ns0:mobileNumbers>'.
'<ns0:category>PROMOTIONAL</ns0:category>'.
'</ns0:singleMessage>'.
'</ns0:BulkMessage>';

$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($payload);
```

Please help!

Comment: have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906010/storing-xml-inside-json-object

Comment: Why not base64encode it before adding as payload? Or just remove all `\r` and `\n`

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. The result i am getting actually doesnt have line breaks

Comment: @xeo i looked at that question and i failed to see how i can apply it to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **I'm wondering why you are interfacing with an API in JSON and sending an XML payload? Can't you send the XML directly?**

Regardless, you aren't using "json_encode" properly. You need to represent your data into an array or object.

Here's what you want to do

```
<?php
$payloadArr = array(
    'payload'=>
        '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>'.
        '<ns0:BulkMessage xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema BulkMessageSchema.xsd\">'.
        '<ns0:bulkType>SINGLE</ns0:bulkType>'.
        '<ns0:singleMessage>'.
        '<ns0:message>Sample single bulk message</ns0:message>'.
        '<ns0:reference>'.$uid.'</ns0:reference>'.
        '<ns0:mobileNumbers>0773562319</ns0:mobileNumbers>'.
        '<ns0:mobileNumbers>0774705932</ns0:mobileNumbers>'.
        '<ns0:category>PROMOTIONAL</ns0:category>'.
        '</ns0:singleMessage>'.
        '</ns0:BulkMessage>'
);

$payloadJson = json_encode($payloadArr);

header('Content-type: application/json;');
echo $payloadJson;
```

The result I'm getting seems like what you want :

```
{ payload: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ns0:BulkMessage xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:ns0=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema\" xsi:schemaLocation=\"http://www.econet.co.zw/BulkMessageSchema BulkMessageSchema.xsd\"><ns0:bulkType>SINGLE</ns0:bulkType><ns0:singleMessage><ns0:message>Sample single bulk message</ns0:message><ns0:reference></ns0:reference><ns0:mobileNumbers>0773562319</ns0:mobileNumbers><ns0:mobileNumbers>0774705932</ns0:mobileNumbers><ns0:category>PROMOTIONAL</ns0:category></ns0:singleMessage></ns0:BulkMessage>" }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It turns out that doing output printout using var_dump instead of echo is the problem, so its now coming out. But it xml is coming out with extra back slashes, is there a way of removing these?

Comment: The backslashes need to be there to escape the quotes and stay standard JSON