# Is embedding an XML style possible in a Cytoscape network json file?

Tags: cytoscape

Maybe this is an obvious question or perhaps it's simply not possible but our team is trying to add export functionality to our webapp and we would require users to use our specific Cytoscape style.xml file alongside their exported graph. Ideally though we'd just embed the style into the json. Is this possible?

Comment: Same answer applies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906010/storing-xml-inside-json-object

Comment: Actually, this isn't the same as the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906010/storing-xml-inside-json-object  The OP is asking about functionality between Cytoscape.js and Cytoscape desktop

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is "no".  Currently, there is no way that I know of to export cytoscape desktop styles for visualization in cytoscape.js.  We have the same requirement and could not find an easy solution.  On the other hand, you can export your network as a CX file, which includes information about styles and then visualize that with cytoscape.js.